# Chrome headless executes test over 40 seconds

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

I have issue with running tests in headless mode with chrome options.

`ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); options.addArguments("--headless");  driver = new ChromeDriver(options);`

In UI mode test is executed fast(4seconds), but when I enable headless mode (40 seconds)

[Headless mode:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6Yhl.png)

[UI mode:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ei2TP.png)

Is there any other way to use chrome headless, whether something is changed in the mean time in driver itself? I have tried with different java, browser version and chrome driver and issue is the same..

Selenium 4.3.0, TestNG 7.4.0